# Efficiency of len() and pop() in Python

Tags: python, performance

Why is this Significantly faster with comments? Shouldn't a pop, a comparison, and a length check be O(1)? Would that significantly affect the speed?

```
#! /usr/bin/python                                                                
import math                                                                       

pmarbs = []                                                                       
pows = 49                                                                         
pmarbs.append("W")                                                                
inc = 1                                                                           
for i in range(pows):                                                             
    count = 0                                                                     
    j = 0                                                                         
    ran = int(pow(2, i))                                                          
    marker = len(pmarbs) - inc                                                    
    while (j < ran):                                                              
        #potential marble choice                                                  
        pot = pmarbs[marker - j]                                                  
        pot1 = pot + "W"                                                          
        pot2 = pot + "B"                                                          

        if (pot2.count('W') < pot2.count('B')) and (len(pot2) > (i+1)):           
            count += 1                                                            
        else:                                                                     
            pmarbs.append(pot2)                                                   

        pmarbs.append(pot1)                                                       
#        if(len(pmarbs[0]) < i):                                                  
#           pmarbs.pop(0)                                                         
#           marker -= 1                                                           
        j += 1                                                                    


    if (count != 0):                                                              
        print(count)                                                              
        print("length of pmarbs = %s" % len(pmarbs))
```

UPDATE: 
I'm making the question shorter, because the code being significantly slower was my question. I cared less about the code getting killed at runtime.

Comment: What does "get killed" mean?  If you get some sort of exception, show the exact error message with the traceback.  BTW, do you realize how large 2**49 is?

Comment: Are you *really* asking why executing more code takes more time than executing less code?

Comment: @kindall the other way around: why is executing more code faster than executing less.

Comment: There are so many double negatives it's hard to know what the OP meant ;-)

Comment: I tried to run this. That appears to have been a bad idea; I almost had to hard reboot.

Comment: What environment are you running this in?

Comment: Okay, I'm still trying to figure out why this formatting isn't working. I apologize for all of the double negatives. I think I fixed that. I'm running this on Ubuntu on my Laptop.

Comment: @Nirk, Kindall is right about what I'm asking, but I'm asking why it would **significantly** affect the run time, because all of the operations **I mentioned above** are O(1). Is it just because of the number of times I'm executing the code?

Comment: "all of the operations are O(1)" - no, they're not.

Comment: I was referring to the commented operations (The Pop, the Length and the comparison). Unless those aren't O(1). In which case, that would be the answer to my question.

Comment: `pop(0)` requires shifting all the other elements of the list, which takes time proportional to the size of the list. I don't think that's the answer to your problem, though.

Comment: Wait, is this faster when the code is commented out, or when it's left in? If it's faster when the code is commented out, it's probably the `pop(0)`'s fault.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what it is now. Thank you very much for your help.

The code is faster with the comments included.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just to answer part of the question:  popping from the end (the *right* end) of a list takes constant time in CPython, but popping from the left end (`.pop(0)`) takes time proportional to the length of the list:  *all* the elements in `the_list[1:]` are physically moved one position to the left.

If you need to delete index position 0 frequently, much better to use an instance of `collections.deque`.  Deques support efficient pushing and popping from both ends.

BTW, when I run the program, I get a clean exception:

```
...
length of pmarbs = 8306108
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 22, in <module>
    pmarbs.append(pot2)
MemoryError
```

That happened to be on a 32-bit Windows box.  And it doesn't surprise me ;-)

Comment: That answers most of my question. I can probably figure out the rest on my own. Thank you!

Comment: @DerekHalden, see my edit just now:  I get a clean `MemoryError` exception.

Answer (score 12):

`list.pop(index)` is an `O(n)` operation, because after you remove the value from the list, you have to shift the memory location of every other value in the list over one. Calling `pop` repeatedly on large lists is great way to waste computing cycles. If you absolutely must remove from the front of a large list over and over use `collections.deque`, which will give you much faster insertions and deletions to thr front.

`len()` is `O(1)` *because* deletions are `O(n)`, since if you make sure all the values in a list are allocated in memory right next to each other, the total length of a list is just the tail's memory location - the head's memory location. If you don't care about the performance of `len()` and similar operations, then you can use a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) to do constant time insertions and deletions - that just makes `len()` be `O(n)` and `pop()` be `O(1)` (and you get some other funky stuff like `O(n)` lookups).

Everything I said about `pop()` goes for `insert()` also - except for `append()`, which usually takes `O(1)`.

I recently worked on a problem that required deleting lots of elements from a very large list (around 10,000,000 integers) and my initial dumb implementation just used `pop()` every time I needed to delete something - that turned out to not work at all, because it took `O(n)` to do even one cycle of the algorithm, which itself needed to `n` times.

My solution was to create a `set()` called `ignore` in which I kept the indices of all "deleted" elements. I had little helper functions to help me not have to think about skipping these, so my algorithm didn't get too ugly. What eventually did it was doing a single `O(n)` pass every 10,000 iterations to delete all the elements in `ignore` and make ignore empty again, that way I got the increased performance from a shrinking list while only having to do one 10,000th of the work for my deletions.

Also, ya, you should get a memory error because you are trying to allocate a list that is definitely much larger than your hard drive - much less your memory.