# Space complexity when making input smaller

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

Imagine you want to find all the duplicates in an array, and you must do this in `O(1)` space and `O(N)` time.

An algorithm like this would have `O(N)` space:

```
def find_duplicates(arr):

    seen = set()
    res = []
    for i in arr:
        if i in seen: res.append(i)
        seen.add(i)
    return res
```

My question is would the following algorithm use `O(1)` space or `O(N)` space:

```
def find_duplicates(arr):

    seen = set()
    res = []
    while arr:
        i = arr.pop()
        if i in seen: res.append(i)
        seen.add(i)
    return res
```

Technically `arr` gets smaller and the sum of `|seen|` and `|arr|` will always be less than the original `|arr|`, but at the end of the day I think it's still allocating `|arr|` space for `seen`.

Comment: I think you have small idea about big O notation. Read this and get some idea my brother. good luck.
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/analyzing-complexity-code-python

Comment: You are correct in your analysis. Space complexity is O(n) as you said because `seen` grows with input. You can also consider a case where an array has all unique integers already. Worst case for your second approach is still O(n).

Comment: You could get O(1) space complexity *if* `seen` were reusing the space left unneeded by `arr`. But it isn't. `arr.pop()` doesn't necessarily release *any* memory; it is retained to avoid the need to reallocate memory for future additions to `arr`.

Comment: @chepner would you mind writing an answer? The question looks like it stem from whether `.pop()` releases any memory. My assumption is that for small arrays it will be ~`O(N)` space but then once you hit large arrays `pop()` releases more memory and results in `O(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine the space complexity, you have to know something about how `pop` is implemented, as well as how Python manages memory. In order for your algorithm to use constant space, `arr` would have to release the memory used by popped items, and `seen` would have to be able to reuse that memory. However, most implementations of Python *probably* do not support that level of sharing. In particular, `pop` isn't going to release any memory; it will keep it against the possibility of needing it in the future, rather than having to ask to get the memory back.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you try to do time and space complexity analysis, think of a test case which could blow up your program the most.

Your space complexity is O(N). In the case of your second program, if you have a list of numbers with only 1s. Eg: `x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`. Then you'll see that `res` grows almost to the size of N. Consider what happens when you have all different numbers. `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`. Now `seen` grows to the size of N.

Also thinking about time complexity, the `pop()` function of python lists could sometime be a problem. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441488/efficiency-of-len-and-pop-in-python) for more details.