# Performance of BFS in Python 3, two implementations, very different execution times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently in a Programming competition where time is key, therefore I'm trying to optimize my solution as much as possible. I have to do 30x30 operations of BFS in under 1s. I tried 3 implementations (2 of the same once with lists and once with deque, and 1 of 2D array). Surprisingly, one BFS was done in 0.027 seconds, while the other was done in 0.0023 seconds! I would like to understand why this has happened, as both of them are the same.

Implementation 1

```
def BFS3(grid, start):
    queue = deque([start])
    visited = deque([start])
    while queue:
        current_point = queue.popleft()
        if grid[current_point.y][current_point.x] == -1:
            continue

        adjacent_points = current_point.get_adjacents(grid)
        for point in adjacent_points:
            if grid[point.y][point.x] == -1:
                continue
            if (point.x, point.y) in visited:
                continue
            visited.append(point)
            queue.append(point)
    return visited
```

Implementation 2

```
def BFS4(grid, start):
    visited = []
    for _ in range(height):
        visited.append([0]*width)

    queue = [start]
    _x, _y = start.x, start.y
    visited[_y][_x] = 1
    while queue:
        current_point = queue.pop(0)
        if grid[current_point.y][current_point.x] == -1:
            continue

        adjacent_points = current_point.get_adjacents(grid)
        for point in adjacent_points:
            if grid[point.y][point.x] == -1:
                continue
            if visited[point.y][point.x]:
                continue
            _x, _y = point.x, point.y
            visited[_y][_x] = 1
            queue.append(point)
    return visited
```

and here is the main:

```
start_point = Point(30, 3)
new_grid = deepcopy(rows)
timer = time()
test = BFS4(rows, start_point)
print_debug("Timer: ", time() - timer)

start_point = Point(30, 3)
new_grid = deepcopy(rows)
timer = time()
test = BFS3(rows, start_point)
print_debug("Timer: ", time() - timer)
```

Output:

```
Timer:  0.002305269241333008
Timer:  0.027254581451416016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the `pop(0)` function of built-in type `list` is `O(n)` making it considerably more time consuming than `deque` with `O(1)`

Also see this thread [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441488/efficiency-of-len-and-pop-in-python)

There are multiple components in the two Implementations that differ in performance.

1) `deque.popleft()` has a runtime of `O(1)` compared to `list.pop()` which is in the order of `O(n)`

2) The way you look up the visited nodes:

- In **Implementation 2** visited is a `N x N matrix` with `boolish` values looked up by coordinates `visited[x][y]` which has a lookup of `O(1)` however also has to store N^2 values being very inefficient storage wise for sparse matrixes
- In **Implementation 1** you use `(x, y) in visited` which utilizes the `overwriten  __contain__()` function, which most certainly is a search algorithm, that at best is `O(log(n))` at worst `O(n)` negatively scaling with the number of nodes

An alternative implementation for `visited` would be a `hashtable` which the Python native `dict` is. It also has a lookup time in the order of `O(1)`, but only saves the 1s of the visited matrix with 
`dict[(x,y)] = 1` for setting and `dict.get((x,y))`. However **note** that hashtables come with an overhead.

If you are just concerned with runtime and RAM usage is neglectable you can stick with the matrix, as (I suspect) it should be faster than the hashtable.

Comment: Although this deems to be true, but in my case the function where I'm using list is the one taking less time.

Comment: Then I would take a closer look at ```if (point.x, point.y) in visited:
                continue```, because in implementation 2 the lookup is by index in a nested list, which is also ```O(1)``` but the implementation of ```__contains__()``` could be very different. I would guess it's some kind of search implementation which at best would be ```O(log(n))```

Comment: You could use a ```dict``` instead of ```deque``` for the visited structure as you primarily search within that one, and dict lookups (hashtables) are also in the order of ```O(1)```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now that you brought my attention to it, yes the O(1) indexing is the advantage here. Thank you. As for using the dictionary, I wouldn't want that since I'm dealing with an ordered queue, unless I missed your point.

Comment: Yes, you did. The ordered queue is relevent, well for your queue object, where  you need it. The visited object is for lookups, therefore the queue property is useless. So your two options are as implementation 2 a matrix with book values, you access by coordinates ```visited[x][y]```, however for a non sense matrix, that is a lot of RAM for only a view values. A visited dict would be as fast with lookups, but smaller, as only the true values are in.

Comment: Now I understand your point, thanks. So I would need to encode the coordinates into a dictionary key, which will be the equivalent of having only the values where "1" exists in the 2D Array. If I may suggest you edit your answer to what we discussed in the comments so that I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, is that a comprehensive summary of the discussed?